# update a textview in a fragment from a fragmentActivity

Tags: android, textview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am reading data from a bluetooth stream, when the strings I read are temperature values I want to update a textview to that value.
The problem is I read the data from a fragmentactivity and my textview is inside a fragment.
Can anyone help me?

this is the code where I collect the bluetooth data (The actual collecting is left out)

```
public class ListResult extends FragmentActivity implements SearchResult.OnSearchResultSelectedListener {
ProgressDialog pd;

RecipeInstructions instructions = new RecipeInstructions();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    ...

            mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
                int end = (int)msg.arg2;
                String writeMessage;
                switch(msg.what) {
                    case 1:
                        /*
                        check the bluetooth message, which is sent by the Arduino bluetooth module
                        depending on the message different tasks will be executed
                        the swipe gestures, the temperature sensor, the weigh scale
                        */
                        writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                        writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                        int position = pager.getCurrentItem();
                        Log.e("BLUETOOTH", writeMessage);
                        if(writeMessage.contains("RIGHT")) {
                            Log.e("SCROLL", "if function");
                            index = position -1;
                            scroll();
                        }
                        else if(writeMessage.contains("LEFT")) {
                            Log.e("SCROLL", "if function");
                            index = position +1;
                            scroll();
                        }
                        else if(writeMessage.contains("Temperature")) {
                            setTemp(writeMessage);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

}

public void setTemp(String message){
    String value = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf(" ")+1, message.length());
    instructions.setTemp(value + "°C");
}
```

This is my fragment

```
public class RecipeInstructions extends Fragment {
LinearLayout ll;
RelativeLayout ll1;
TextView textview;
TextView desc;
ImageView imgview;
ImageView temp;
TextView tempValue;
ScrollView scroll;
String temperature;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ing_check, container, false);

    ...

    tempValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempValue);
    tempValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new ImageDownloader(imgview).execute( createNewUrl(((ListResult) getActivity()).getUrl()));

    return v;
}

public void setTemp(String temperature){
    tempValue.setText(temperature);
    Log.e("TEMP", "t= " + this.temperature);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the fragment instance in the activity by using

```
  fragment=  fragmentManager.findFragmentById (fragmentId);
```

or

```
  fragment=  fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (FragmentTag);
```

Now you can set the data to the TextView inside the fragment.

```
((RecipeInstructions)fragment).setData(data);
```

Implement the method `setData` in the `Fragment`

```
public class RecipeInstructions extends Fragment {
// ....
public void setData(String data){
textView.setText(data);
}
// .....
```

Comment: my fragment class uses a simple layout, I don't have an id or a tag for a fragment (I think, this is new to me)

Comment: Tag for the fragment is given at the time of a adding the fragment to fragment manager like
fragmentTransaction.add(fragment,TAG); where as fragmentId is ID of container to which the fragment is attached.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)